# API to download documents from shared links

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was trying to download documents from a shared link via API. I couldn't find any other way except adding download=1 inside the url parameter. However, that doesn't work if the shared link has restricted access, I couldn't download the file even when I'm authenticated via oauth2.0. 
Questions:
Is there other API ways to download via share links?
How to I authenticate myself using api for share links.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if "Block Download" is enabled for this document link or not?